# BERT Self-Attention layer

Tags: nlp, bert

I am trying to use the **first** individual [BertSelfAttention](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L213) layer for the BERT-base model, but the model I am loading from `torch.hub` seems to be different then the one used in hugginface `transformers.models.bert.modeling_bert`:

```
import torch, transformers

tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
torch_model = torch.hub.load('huggingface/pytorch-transformers', 'model', 'bert-base-uncased')

inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus("Hello", "World", return_tensors='pt')

output_embedding = torch_model.embeddings(inputs['input_ids'], inputs['token_type_ids'])

output_self_attention = torch_model.encoder.layer[0].attention.self(output_embedding)[0]

# compare output with using the huggingface model directly
bert_self_attn = transformers.models.bert.modeling_bert.BertSelfAttention(torch_model.config) 

# transfer all parameters
bert_self_attn.load_state_dict(torch_model.encoder.layer[0].attention.self.state_dict())
# <All keys matched successfully>

output_self_attention2 = bert_self_attn(output_embedding)[0]
output_self_attention != output_self_attention2 # tensors are not equal?
```

Why is `output_self_attention2` different from `output_self_attention`? I thought they would give the same output given the same input.

Comment: The output from ```BertSelfAttention``` seems to be different each time. Is this because of the ```dropout``` layer? I thought ```dropout``` only affected the backward pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the models in training mode (the default mode), and the stochastic elements like dropout are active in training mode, therefore you obtain different results, not only between different models, but also on different runs of the same model.

You should invoke `model.eval()`, which makes some elements like dropout or batch normalization behave in inference mode, i.e. dropout is disabled altogether, batch-normalization uses the remembered statistics.

Also, it is better to avoid gradients being computed with `torch.no_grad()`, as you do not need them. The same effect can be achieved with `torch.set_grad_enabled(False)`.

```
import torch, transformers


torch.set_grad_enabled(False) # avoid wasting computation with gradients


tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
torch_model = torch.hub.load('huggingface/pytorch-transformers', 'model', 'bert-base-uncased')

torch_model.eval() # <------ set model in inference mode  

inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus("Hello", "World", return_tensors='pt')
output_embedding = torch_model.embeddings(inputs['input_ids'], inputs['token_type_ids'])
output_self_attention = torch_model.encoder.layer[0].attention.self(output_embedding)[0]


# compare output with using the huggingface model directly
bert_self_attn = transformers.models.bert.modeling_bert.BertSelfAttention(torch_model.config) 
bert_self_attn.load_state_dict(torch_model.encoder.layer[0].attention.self.state_dict())

bert_self_attn.eval()  # <------ set model in inference mode  

output_self_attention2 = bert_self_attn(output_embedding)[0]
output_self_attention != output_self_attention2 # tensors are equal
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `dropout = 0.0` solves this issue:

```
torch_model.encoder.layer[0].attention.self.dropout.p = 0.0
bert_self_attn.dropout.p = 0.0
```

I thought that `dropout` was only used during the training process. Is the `dropout` in BERT different from conventional `dropout` layers?

Comment: Please have a look at the answer I posted, which explains what the underlying problem is.